# Accessing Mainframe datasets using FTP form Python

Tags: python, mainframe, ftplib

I want to download a dataset from mainframe using Python ftplib.

I am able to login to mainframe and I get default working directory as "CY$$."
I want to change the working directory to "CY01."
I tried using ftp.cwd('CY01.') but it changes the directory to "CY$$.CY01." instead of just "CY01."

While using command prompt I use below command to successfully change working directory:

CD 'CY01.'

(a '.' at end of directory name is IBM command to change default working directory and not append it to defualt directory)

I also tried ftp.sendcmd("CD 'CY01.'") but it gives error "500 unknown command CD"

Can someone please help with changing the defualt working directory?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to change the working directory? can't you just use the GET command and FTP it regardless of your working directory? When I am FTPing files from the mainframe, I never change my working directory because there is no reason to. When you the GET command it'll ask for the location of the Remote file, then the location of the local file.

Comment: @SaggingRufus thanks for replying.
It would be a great help if you can elaborate on how to use GET command through Python to download a dataset from mainframe.

Comment: If that is not documented, how were you proposing to do it? Work with the Mainframe technical staff. Tell them what you want to do. They will confirm that it is OK, or tell you how they want it done. Then you implement it with "Python ftplib", or whatever else.

Comment: @ParthKaria I don't know how to use it via python, but the python must be interfacing with the same FTP server that your command line is. I would assume that you could just use ftp.sendcmd(GET 'remote dataset name' local dataset name)

Comment: WRT changing the working directory just put the HLQ in quotes ftp.cwd("'CY01'").

Comment: @DavidCrayford Thanks a ton. Your solution worked!!

Comment: @ParthKaria give me a hit then mate. I could do with all the reputation points I can take!

Comment: @DavidCrayford, I really want to upvote your solution. But I dont get an option to do so as I am a new joiner. Please let me know if there any other way to upvote your solution and I will definitely do so.

Answer (score 0):

ftplib ccommand ftp.cwd("'CY01'") works fine. Have been using it for over a year now.